# Configure Linux bash to understand "cd.."

Tags: command-line, bash, mingw32

In the Windows command prompt, both `cd ..` and `cd..` move to the parent directory. On Linux bash (MINGW, etc) the former works, but the latter gives an error: `cd..: command not found`.

Perhaps naive, but is there a Linux setting or can bash be configured to understand `cd..` (and to operate like `cd ..`)?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Maybe because he makes many typing mistakes. I have a lot of aliases and spelling rules for my most common typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```

Use an alias.

Comment: Works, thanks! Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 (added alias to `~/.bashrc` as noted by @Pilot6). Also tested in `git-bash` on Windows where I created `%USERPROFILE%\.bash_profile` and added the alias in there.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to `~/.bashrc`

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is, like alias, to use a function.

```
function cd..()
{
    cd ..
}
```

(But here - the use case being simple - I'd prefer an alias :)

In general, a function may be more useful when there's more/other logic involved.